# How to draw unicode text symbols such as snowman with Cairo in C?

Tags: c, unicode, cairo

I'm trying to draw Unicode symbols such as snowman (☃) or mountain (⛰). Drawing Greek (e.g. ή, 2 bytes in UTF-8) or Euro sign (€, 3 bytes in UTF-8) works, but none of the more "complicated" symbols (⛱⛲⛳⛴...) works.

I'm on Ubuntu and I tested mostly with Ubuntu font. It seems to support those because I can see the symbols correctly in my text editor, in the command line and elsewhere. Is it possible to actually draw those Unicode symbols with Cairo using some common font?

I would like to know how to draw the symbols preferably in a cross-platform way in C and without additional dependencies (such as pango) if possible.

My example code follows. I get the same results when I use the so called toy API and when I use Python (pycairo which currently exposes only the toy API).

The code:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <cairo-ft.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cairo_surface_t *surface;
    cairo_t *cr;
    cairo_font_face_t *face;
    cairo_status_t status;
    cairo_glyph_t *glyphs = NULL;
    int num_glyphs;
    FcPattern *pattern;
    FcResult result;
    char *name = "Ubuntu";

    char *utf8;
    if (argc > 1)
        utf8 = argv[1];
    else
        utf8 = "ε";
    double x = 5;
    double y = 40;

    surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 200, 50);
    cr = cairo_create(surface);

    FcInit();
    pattern = FcNameParse(name);
    FcDefaultSubstitute(pattern);
    FcConfigSubstitute(FcConfigGetCurrent(), pattern, FcMatchPattern);
    pattern = FcFontMatch(FcConfigGetCurrent(), pattern, &result);
    face = cairo_ft_font_face_create_for_pattern(pattern);
    cairo_set_font_face(cr, face);

    status = cairo_scaled_font_text_to_glyphs(cairo_get_scaled_font(cr),
                                              x, y,
                                              utf8, -1,
                                              &glyphs, &num_glyphs,
                                              NULL, NULL,
                                              NULL);

    if (status == CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        printf("num_glyphs: %d (strlen: %zd)\n", num_glyphs, strlen(utf8));
        for (int i = 0; i < num_glyphs; i++)
            printf("index: %lu\n", glyphs[i].index);
        cairo_show_glyphs(cr, glyphs, num_glyphs);
        cairo_glyph_free(glyphs);
    }
    else {
        printf("cairo_scaled_font_text_to_glyphs: %s\n",  cairo_status_to_string(status));
    }

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "out.png");
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
}
```

To compile:

```
cc -o text `pkg-config --cflags cairo` main.c -lfontconfig `pkg-config --libs cairo`
```

To execute:

```
./text ☃
```

The result should be in `out.png`.

Comment: I believe we've seen problems with complex characters before on the toy API. Does Python have a Pango binding you could try out?

Comment: Yes, it does work with pango and pangocairo in Python. When I use `CairoContext` and `FontDescription` classes (e.g. https://www.cairographics.org/cookbook/pycairo_pango). Python `cairo` package doc (https://www.cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/text.html) says do not use the toy API for complex scripts like Hebrew and Arabic and use `pangocairo` for glyphs. But I'm in C, not using the toy API, and I assume(d) that snowman is simpler because it does not deal with kerning or left-to-right.

Comment: Are you saying that the snowman is an example for something that does not work? Because it works for me here.

Comment: Ok, I do not have the Ubuntu font. Adding a call to FcPatternPrint(pattern); before creating the font face tells me that it uses the DejaVu Sans font here.

Comment: @UliSchlachter Right! DejaVuSans works for me with snowman. I missed that before. However, none of these ⛰⛱⛲⛳⛴⛵⛶⛷⛸⛹⛺⛻⛼⛽⛾ works which at the end makes sense xfd does not report them for DejaVuSans. And it does not report any symbols like these for `xfd -fa "Ubuntu"`. I assumed that when I see them and my system font is Ubuntu, they are there. I guess something more complicated is going on there.

Comment: As far as I know, Pango does something like font substitution. If the selected font does not have some necessary glyph, it looks for a closely related font with the character and uses it for this one glyph.